# Showing ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I have implemented one app which is running successfully on marshmallow version but when I am running on kitkat version then it shows the exception i.e. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. I don't know why this exception is coming while I am using min sdk version is 16 and max is 25 please check the following image

[image: log_cat_image]

splash on Mainfest

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.devbhoomimedia.maangal.SplashActivity"
        android:label="Maangal.com"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

gradle file

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.devbhoomimedia.mgltest"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] 
 } 
 }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
compile project(path: ':library')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.0'
compile project(':library_spinner')
}
```

Comment: Post the logcat in text form instead of an image.

Comment: post your gradle file

Comment: And also add your manifest entry

Comment: please check my updated question

Comment: @FWeigl please click on image it will show clear thanku

Comment: @user6734679 Remove `multiDexEnabled = true` from gradle file

Comment: @vm345 I have remove it then work properly thanku so much

Comment: @user6734679 This is not about me not being able to see your image, it is about a. people being able to copy parts of the logcat and b. Google being able to index your question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `multiDexEnabled = true` from gradle files